# Whether my own driver needs digital signing in Windows 7 x64

Tags: c++, driver, windows-7-x64, wdk

I have created driver to hook ssdt on windows 7 x64. I have one doubt whether I need to digitally sign my driver to install in kernel mode on x64 or else I need just windows drive kit to install it.

Is there any other code or commmands to install a driver in kernel mode other than the Windows Driver Kit(WDK) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a driver you can use the built-in command-line tool `sc.exe`. For example:

```
sc create MyDriver type= kernel binPath= c:\mydriver.sys
```

**ATTENTION**: You shouldn't hook SSDT on x64 because of [The Patch Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection).

Comment: i already disable the patch guard.i want to create a software to hook ssdt so i need  other type of way to install the driver because users can't able to type this command so  to avoid that any other options there to install driver?

Comment: @darkendemon: what about bat-file? your own executable which starts sc.exe or uses SCM manager directly?

Comment: :I am beginner in ring 0.Is a bat or .cmd file is enough to install a driver?.i didn't create a software till now.i am trying for that only.so can u explain about sc.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on 64-bit Windows you **must** sign your drivers.

For test and development purposes only, you can temporarily enable drivers signed with test certificate that provided in WDK by pressing F8 at boot and selecting “Disable Driver Signature Enforcement“.
However, you will have to do this manually on every boot.

There are few more methods described [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/loading-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-7-and-vista-64-bit-x64/), but some of these methods no longer work on Win7 SP1, and what works has so many restrictions and inconveniences, that you are effectively forced to actually sign your drivers with real certificate.

Comment: Is there any other code or commmands to install a driver in kernel mode other than the Windows Driver Kit(WDK)

Comment: That's not true, I've developed drivers and test signing + boot with TESTSIGNING on does the trick, and I didn't need to aways "Disable Driver Signature Enforcement". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: the command   `bcedit /set testsigning on`  will let you install unsigned drivers, and the setting does not go away until you explicitly turn it off. my installation (win 7 x64 ultimate sp1) has been in this mode for over 7 months and its perfectly fine, with some unsigned drivers installed. if you're not distributing the driver I'd say don't waste your money.

Comment: Having testsigning mode all over the screen and necessity to painfully enable it by bcdedit is exactly what I meant by **"what works has many restrictions and inconveniences"** - you cannot distribute this to any reasonable user

Comment: no reasonable user will make use of ReadyDriver hack. After development, it should just be signed with a proper certificate.

Comment: Thats exactly what I said - you *must sign it*. For development, there are nasty hacks, and I did mention them.

Comment: It's wrong when you say for development he must aways do something at boot. FALSE. That's not the single option for a development machine. And for development, he's not left forced to sign it with a real certificate because of that. That's what you suggest, and it's not true.

Comment: @mvp from the question its obvious that op is still in development stage, at that stage its impossible to get a certificate from ms, the only option is testsigning, no escaping that. and about releasing the drivers test-signed it has been done before, ppjoy did this for some time, its normally done for free software, the bcedit command can be run by your installer, for commercial software however its best to sign it properly

Answer (score 0):

For a development machine, execute `bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON`. You will get watermarks at your desktop for this mode, don't care about them, avoid using ReadyDriver.

Create a test certificate for you, install it at your machine.

Reboot.

Now it's just a matter of test signing your drivers and installing them.

[The TESTSIGNING Boot Configuration Option (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Signing Drivers during Development and Test (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You'll need the tools to test sign your drivers. From what I recall, other options became unreliable as Windows got updated. For me this was the best approach.