# How to install my own driver in kernel model windows-7 x64

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, wdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whether my own driver needs digital signing in Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251481/whether-my-own-driver-needs-digital-signing-in-windows-7-x64)

I have created driver to hook ssdt on windows 7 x64.Is there any other code or commmands to install a driver in kernel mode other than the Windows Driver Kit(WDK) ?